# git hooks and how they work

Tags: git, hook

So I'm trying to get hudson to build with a post-receive hook.  In my local git repo I set post-receive.sample to just post-receive, chmod 755 and added in the line:

```
/usr/bin/curl -u user:secret http://localhost:8080/hudson/job/MyJob/build?token=secondsecret
```

If I force a build, hudson updates the code, but here's what I don't understand, the hooks in that repo DON't have the .sample after them like they do locally, and the post-receive in the hudson repo doesn't have that line of code above.  What's going on here and how are hooks integrated into the whole git process?  Do I need to be changing this hook on the remote repo?  I would have thought it was enough to do it locally and push so anyone fetching from that repo get the new hooks.  I can't understand how another user's repo would have different hooks.

Comment: I don't wuite understand the question. When you push to remote repository, the remote repository `post-receive` hook is invoked **on remote repository**.

Comment: ya but my point is that it doesn't seem to be invoking my curl command,  if I manually run that, hudson runs a build, when I do a push, no build is run.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1. Place the `post-receive` hook on the *server* and let the server run curl.
2. Place a `post-commit` hook on your local repo and let your local box run curl.

As your build job will probably fetch the code to build from the repo on the *server*, only option 1. makes sense. In case 2., the build job would probably have to fetch the code from your local box, and that is probably not what you want.

You cannot place hooks onto the *server* using `git push`. You (or someone with the appropriate permissions) needs to do that by manually logging into *server* and modifying the hook script files locally.

Answer (score 11):

Hooks are not shared through the repository. You need to install the hook at the remote side.

Comment: but adding the hook to my local one should invoke the command on the server no?  otherwise what's the point of the hook?

Comment: +1 Hooks are not version controlled and are not shared between repositories.  Mainly this is for security reasons -- it's one thing to let someone push code into your repo, it's another to let them **run** code on your sever.  Also, it often doesn't make sense for everyone to have the same hooks -- platforms may be different, paths may be different, the servers may have different purposes (staging, CI, deployment, QA, etc.).

Comment: so writing hooks in my local repo does effectively nothing then?

Comment: @brad You can use it for house keeping tasks like running the test before every commit